# Why can't this jekyll plugin locate mini_magick even when it's installed?

Tags: jekyll-extensions

I am trying to install this [Image thumbnailing plugin for Jekyll/octopress](https://github.com/mrdanadams/jekyll-thumbnailer) onto my Jekyll site, but Jekyll can't find the mini_magick gem.

I already installed ImageMagick, one of the prerequisites, using `brew install ImageMagick`.

I also installed mini_magick, which is a ruby wrapper for ImageMagick, using `gem install mini_magick`. The response was:

```
Successfully installed mini_magick-4.0.2
Parsing documentation for mini_magick-4.0.2
1 gem installed
```

When I enter `gem list mini_magick` I get this response:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

mini_magick (4.0.2)
```

Yet when I enter `jekyll serve` to build my site, having integrated the thumbnail plugin that requires mini_magick, I get this error:

```
/Users/tjohnson/projects/resolve/_plugins/thumbnail.rb:21:in `require': cannot load such file -- mini_magick (LoadError)from /Users/tjohnson/projects/resolve/_plugins/thumbnail.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
```

When I type `bundle show mini_magick` I get this response:

```
`Could not find gem 'mini_magick'.
```

How is that mini_magick can be installed but not found by Jekyll? I'm new to Rubygems. Are there separate gem files for different projects, and somehow I installed the mini_magick gem into a different gem directory than my Jekyll project?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
bundle exec jekyll server
```

This worked for me after a similar scenario only affecting image_magick.

For me, the error presented after using the [jekyll-picture-tag](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/jekyll-picture-tag) extension. I added the extension's gem to my Gemfile, ran bundler install, it installed all dependencies that was confirmed with bundle show. After using this bundler approach to run Jekyll, the error self-resolved.

Idea gathered from a [Jekyll support thread](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3084) tackling a different but similar problem.